# ChartJS: Is it possible to omit last grid line to save space

Tags: chart.js, ng2-charts

I'm trying to achieve the behavior shown in the chart below (rendered with another library), where the last grid line on y-axis is omitted in order to avoid excess empty space in the chart. ChartJS seems to insist on including the grid line at value 50 in this case. I've tried using the axis.ticks.max setting, and tried omitting ticks via the ticks callbacks, but neither had the desired effect. Note: I'm hoping for a solution where ChartJS chooses the ticks and range, not one where I have to manually set them all. (BTW, I'm using ChartJS via the ng2-charts wrapper for Angular).

[image: Stacked area chart example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to define a set of `options` in order to obtain the desired result.

- `scales.y.max`
- `scales.y.ticks.callback`
- `scales.y.grid.color`

Please take a look at below runnable code and see how it can be done.

```js
new Chart("chart", {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [{
      label: "My Dataset",
      data: [5, 22, 34, 31, 42, 28, 45]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      y: {
        beginAtZero: true,
        max: 46,
        ticks: {          
          stepSize: 10,
          callback: v => v > 40 ? '' : v
        },
        grid: {
          drawBorder: false,
          color: ctx => ctx.tick.value > 40 ? '#FFF' : '#DDD' 
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart"></canvas>
```